# Menus and text boxes look graphically corrupted in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, xorg

If I let my computer run long enough the screen gets glitchy or graphically corrupted only in certain areas i.e. in text related boxes, menus, menu bars, scroll bars, the system monitor window, etc. It becomes difficult to read what I am typing. Its been happening quite often and I can only fix it by restarting the computer, but its only a matter of time before it happens again. Don't know what else to do, its been a thorn in my side for quite some time now and I need a fix soon because its only gets more frequent until I'm rebooting my computer five times a day. I attached a picture of what happens to this bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1083474

I know I can repeat this bug but I don't know how to catch it and document it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The thing I would do, is make sure my /home/"user name" directory is backed up!!!!

I usually install the system on a partition of 15+GB mounted at / and then have the rest for my /home partition.  That way if I do something funny (which I sometimes do for fun :) I can easily reinstall everything fresh without having to reconfigure anything.  As you may know all your config files are in your ~/ (otherwise known as /home/"user name") directory.

So, first **back up your important stuff** if your computer is having trouble.

If you reinstall and the problem persists you have a serious bug.  I would go with the LTS if that is the case.  You can generate a download script for all your current packages in synaptic package manager as well.  I find fresh installs go smoothly, whereas upgrades have always given my computers trouble (well... maybe not back in the hardy heron days....) Anyway these days I always download an ISO & boot it, and manually partition my computer to use the /home partition as my home partition (ext4... since brtfs isn't ready yet) and then I keep 1 or 2 partitions for an OS.  I would like Ubuntu to offer a separate /home partition as default as it can keep many problems at bay when reinstalling.
No matter what you do **BACKUP your work** if things are going awry

Comment: I have 2 t.b. external hard drive that I back everything up on to every day.  I'm running on my fourth re-install since I tried 12.10.  Although Ironically enough, there hasn't been a problem with it since I posted, maybe it got fixed in an update? I'm not sure.

Comment: There it goes again.  How can I track this bug down?